# gitignore some-path/some-file.ini also ignores some-path/some-file.ini.default

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following line in my gitignore:

```
src/main/resources/properties.ini
```

to exclude that particular `properties.ini` file.

For some reason that *also* excludes the file `src/main/resources/properties.ini.default`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

That `properties.ini.default` file might be excluded/ignored by another `.gitignore` rule, from another `.gitignore` file.

In order to check what is going on, use [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore):

```
git check-ignore -v -- src/main/resources/properties.ini.default
```

You will see immediately which rule from which `.gitignore` file is responsible for ignoring `properties.ini.default`.